Is there a yaml diff tool whose output can be used as input to a yaml patch tool?
There are various yaml-patching tools, e.g. ytt, cels, yamlpatch, and yq. These take as input a yaml document and a patch specification, and output the yaml document that results from applying the given patch to the given yaml document.
Is there an analogous yaml-diffing tool? That is: Is there a tool that, given a pair of yaml documents, produces a (minimal) patch that, when applied to the one document, results in the other document? And produces it in the format that's recognized by some yaml-patching tool?
